# Response is handled incorrectly in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a handler and I have jQuery, which uses ajax to get data from the database and which then needs to be parsed and added to a new array for the FullCalendar calendar. The trouble is that response contains data, but it doesn't want to push them into an array in any way, all strings are undefined.

So, my handler:

```
$bookings = array();
  foreach ($results as $row) {
    $bookingDateTime = $row['booking_datetime'];
      $bookings[] = array(
          'name' => $row['name'],
          'start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($bookingDateTime)),
      );
  }

echo json_encode($bookings);
```

```
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    action: 'get_bookings',
  },
  success: function (response) {
   var events = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
     events.push({
       title: response[i].name,
       start: response[i].start,
     });
   }
   successCallback(events);
   } .....
```

The response contains:

```
[{"name":"luk","start":"2023-11-10"}]
```

But events is empty, more precisely `{name:"undefined",start:"undefined"}`

And what is unclear to me, the entry in response 1, and in events for pushes several.

I will be grateful for any hint. Thanks)

Comment: If `response` is a string, you have to parse it first.

Comment: you can either parse it or define `dataType: 'json'` in `ajax` settings